# How can I change the font size to the same size as my <h2> for the text at the beginning of a paragraph?

Tags: css, fonts, paragraph

When I set it in `<h2></h2>` it automatically makes it a header and wont just stay on the same line as the text.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: it wont stay as h2 is a block element

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

**CSS**

```
.paragraph_style{
    // Copy H2 style into here
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="paragraph_style">Your paragraph</span> will look like this, bla bla...
```

Not sure how your H2 was styled but if it contains attribute `display` take it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `h2` and `h2 + p`(any `p` immediately following an `h2`) to `display: inline`.  This will put them on the same line.  You can also set their `font-size` to be the same.

```css
h2, h2 + p {
  display: inline;
}

h2, p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I've put that in, but it's making the whole page and all the other H2's run the same.
The page has 5 paragraphs. the first paragraph only needs to have the first 4 words appear ( like they are in bold) but the same size as the H2's.
all the others need to stay as normal H2's

Comment: Is it only one `h2` that needs to be treated this way?  If so, then just add a `class` to that one `h2` and style accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`<h2>` is a "block" element: it means it spans all over the width of the page (and "push down" other contents); you should try:

```
h2 {
 display:inline;
}
```

Even if, in my opinion, would be more confortable using a native inline element like `<span class="a_class">...</span>` assign a class, and apply the change to that class

```
.a_class {
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help :-) I'm new to css so it was a tricky one to fix. I tried the replies I got back but had no luck, maybe because it's because I'm using a template?
In the end I contacted the template support and they gave me the following code that worked.
I thought it would be as simple as just changing the font size in html, but no.
Any way, this was the code I got that did the job, seams a lot to change the size though!

```
.page-id-54 .et_pb_text_0 h2:nth-child(1) {
margin-right: 5px;
float: left;
}
.page-id-54 .et_pb_text_0 p:nth-child(2) {
padding-top: 5px;
}
.page-id-54 .et_pb_text_0 h2:nth-child(1) {
margin-bottom: -20px;
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 980px ) {
.page-id-54 .et_pb_text_0 p:nth-child(2) {
padding-top: 0;
}
}
```